# Oracle SQL - How to display 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, number-formatting

Just help me out to display a number whose length is unknown with 2 decimal places.
Example:
If the number is 230000 then i need it to be printed as 230000.00

I tried

```
Select to_char(amount, 'FM99999999.90') as amt from customer;
```

Comment: LPAD & RPAD should do the trick

Comment: seems no problem provided nested within `to_number` function, presumingly Oracle DB

Comment: Please add the related RDBMS tag (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...) to get relevant solution.

Comment: Why just don't add more 9's? I tired that logic ([check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cab415265229890de57c9adb48ffa71)) and with this, you can insert 'unreal' big number to table and still will work.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting is usually front-end "problem"; every decent tool (be it Oracle Apex, Reports, Forms, Jasper Reports, ...) has an option to format a number as you want it. Why? So that those values remain **numbers**, to be able to apply e.g. `SUM` function to them or whatever you may need.

In SQL*Plus (or similar, even GUI tools), formatting is done by the `TO_CHAR` function and desired format mask. If you want two decimals and (just for example) thousands separator, you might do something like this:

```
SQL> with customer (amount) as
  2    (select 230000 from dual union all
  3     select 3.14   from dual union all
  4     select 0.0002 from dual union all
  5     select 25.123 from dual
  6    )
  7  select amount,
  8         to_char(amount, 'fm999g999g990d00') new_amount,
  9    lpad(to_char(amount, 'fm999g999g990d00'), 10, ' ') new_amount2
 10  from customer;

    AMOUNT NEW_AMOUNT      NEW_AMOUNT2
---------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
    230000 230.000,00      230.000,00
      3,14 3,14                  3,14
     ,0002 0,00                  0,00
    25,123 25,12                25,12

SQL>
```

- note that new values have ...`0d00` format mask which makes sure you'll actually see *zeroes* around the decimal point.
- use `G` and `D` for thousand groups and decimals, rather than commas and dots
- `new_amount2`, aditionaly, has `lpad` applied so that values are right-aligned. I presumed that max length of those values is 10 (you'd know better)

---

If you do use SQL*Plus (which is quite rare nowadays), you could even use its `set numformat` command so - no additional modifications are necessary; you just select what you have:

```
SQL> set numformat 999g990d00
SQL>
SQL> with customer (amount) as
  2    (select 230000 from dual union all
  3     select 3.14   from dual union all
  4     select 0.0002 from dual union all
  5     select 25.123 from dual
  6    )
  7  select amount
  8  from customer;

     AMOUNT
-----------
 230.000,00
       3,14
       0,00
      25,12

SQL>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `concat` as follows:

```
select concat(amount, '.00') from customer
```